# Show a div once you onclick and continue to show until clicked again

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have a hover state applied to #ex:

```
$("#ex").hover(function(event) {
    $("#prod").show();
}, function() {
    $("#prod").hide(0).delay(5000);
});
```

However, I also want to have an onclick state applied to #prod, which continues to show, but at the moment it doesn't because of the line I've coded above:

```
$("#prod").hide(0).delay(5000);
```

Any ideas???

Comment: please make a code snippet so that we can test.

Comment: Could you share the markup ? where is #prod compared to #ex ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`stop()`](https://api.jquery.com/stop) method to stop the currently running animation.

```
$("#prod").stop().show();
```

---

Or as *@freedomn-m* suggested - [`finish()`](https://api.jquery.com/finish/) method can be used.

```
$("#prod").finish().show();
```

Comment: Or `finish()` might be more appropriate here.

Answer (score 1):

You should use jQuery's `toggle`, `finish` and `unbind` functions:

```
var firstState = function() {
  $("#ex").hover(function() {
    $("#prod").toggle(500);
  });

  $("#ex").unbind('click').click(secondState);
}

var secondState = function() {
    $("#ex").unbind("mouseenter mouseleave");
    $("#prod").finish();

  $("#ex").unbind('click').click(firstState)
}

firstState();
```

Please find the complete solution: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s6r9kLtk/2)

Comment: Your Fiddle doesn't work. Read the title of question.

Comment: I think the OP wanted it to stay after hover then get released by clicking, but IMO I like this design better it feels like you're more in control with a click. Although the quick back and forth would probably confuse people.+1

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mouseenter` event which only fires when you enter the target area but does not deactivate when leaving. By omitting the `mouseleave` event can you effectively get the target stay indefinitely in a state. The condition in which the target is in can be terminated simply <del>by going back and hover again.</del>* clicking the square.

#### SNIPPET

```js
$('#ex').on('mouseenter', function() {
  $('#prod').show();
});
$('#prod').on('click', function() {
  $(this).hide();
});
```

```css
#ex {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
#prod {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  border: 5px dashed red;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="prod" style="display:none;">Product</div>
<div id='ex'>Hover</div>
```

- Changed procedure due to reassessing question at luke's request.

Comment: Yes it does, when you enter the red circle, so if you cross once and on the way back you cross it again you'll trigger it again. Are you using mobile? Read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseenter#Browser_compatibility

Comment: I've updated the layout so you see it works. 1. Hover over the huge red circle. 2. move your mouse **out** of the red circle. 3. Observe the read square on the right...Is it still there? 4. Next hover over the red circle again. 5. Did the square disappear...?